# Zoom sticker from outside sticker bound

Tags: java, android

I am using stickerview library.
 https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView
everything is working fine except I want the sticker to be zoomed also from out of sticker bound just like in an Instagram story.

In the image attatched..grey points on sticker are the points which is working for drag, zoom or rotation.
And the yellow point for example which is outside the sticker should be able to zoom or rotate sticker.

How can this be done?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Two things: Could you first of all provide a picture of what you imagine? Secondly I think that you should consider your enviroment. You are using a premade library and thus it might be hard for anyone to edit something there.

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot  i have updated the question with a link to image.

Comment: Have you tried to enlarge the sticker boundaries in your code?

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot  if the sticker boundries r enlarged it will overlap other stickers n wont be touchable.plus for sticker to be zoomable from anywhere in the screen the boundries must be full screen.